Calling override value based on boolean (C#, WinForms)
Maybe this is a dumb question but I couldn't find clear and straight clues. I'm using 2 classes for a ToolStripProfessionalRenderer and a ProfessionalColorTable. This is because I'm setting color changes for the menu. For now I got it working but I wanted to write a better code, if possible and simply done. What I'm doing now is this:
    class MenuColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
    {
        bool dark = false;
        public MenuColorTable(string color)
        {
            if (color == "dark")
            {
                dark = true;
                base.UseSystemColors = false;
            }
            else
            {
                base.UseSystemColors = true;
            }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
        {
            get { return dark ? Color.FromArgb(12, 46, 73) : base.MenuItemPressedGradientBegin; }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
        {
            get { return dark ? Color.FromArgb(12, 46, 73) : base.MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd; }
        }
    }


    private class SkinRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        public SkinRenderer(MenuColorTable colorTable) : base(colorTable) { }
    }

Then in the code, for test, I'm calling all this with
menu.Renderer = new SkinRenderer(new MenuColorTable("dark"));

But I'd rather handle this in another more elegant way in the color table. The thing is I realize that basically, having only dark and default colors, base.UseSystemColors would be enough and I wouldn't need to pass default values in the overrides. So, what I don't get how to do is calling those override Colors ONLY if dark is true, instead of calling them regardless and then handling the returning value. Like "if dark, override", so if dark is false the override isn't called, as the default color handles by the environment wouldn't need it.

You can't conditionally override.  Perhaps a better approach is to use a Dictionary with colors that you initialize at program startup, makes the methods very simple.

Also replying to you, your idea is good too...My whole point was literally avoiding defining colors that in theory the environment could handle with default values. Like, if you want to remove all the items from a List, you don't have to manually remove any single item, you can just use the Clear() method that already handles that action. Here it was kinda the same thing, so my most straight take would be "if i have a specific sking, override with defined colors", so if that condition isn't met the environment should handle with default system colors. However, if it can't be done, whatever!

Overriding method is a compile-time operation, you can't control it from runtime - However, you can write your class in a better way:
First, You should limit the users of this class to specific themes, otherwise you might encounter unexpected behavior, and you should avoid using "magic strings", so instead of string color, have your constructor accept a member of the Theme enum.
Second, you don't want to execute the condition each time someone calls your property, so you add an explicit backing field and populate it in the constructor:
enum Theme
{
    Dark,
    // Light, // You might want to add this here
    SystemDefault
}

class MenuColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{

    private Color menuItemPressedGradientBegin, menuItemSelectedGradientEnd;

    public MenuColorTable(Theme theme)
    {
        switch (theme)
        {
            case Theme.Dark:
                // If you have many properties with the same color, 
                // consider using a variable for it:
                var dark = Color.FromArgb(12, 46, 73);
                menuItemPressedGradientBegin = dark;
                menuItemSelectedGradientEnd = dark;
                base.UseSystemColors = false;
                break;


            // If you decide to implement a light theme
            //case Theme.Light:
            //    var light = Color.FromArgb(112, 146, 173);
            //    menuItemPressedGradientBegin = light;
            //    menuItemSelectedGradientEnd = light;
            //    base.UseSystemColors = false;
            //    break;

            case Theme.SystemDefault:

                menuItemPressedGradientBegin = base.MenuItemPressedGradientBegin;
                menuItemSelectedGradientEnd = base.MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd;
                base.UseSystemColors = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin => menuItemPressedGradientBegin;

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd => menuItemSelectedGradientEnd;
}


This is a different way of doing what I'm doing so ok thank you but actually while it's true it may come in handy for other situations, in my case I'm literally trying to avoid this kind of management because actually the thing is "if I have the dark theme, elaborate colors, otherwise do nothing because I'm letting the environment handle the colors with system default colors", so in the second case I wouldn't need to specify all the colors for all the controls. That was the point, in the end. I wanted to avoid specifying colors that in theory the environment could handle itself automatically.

It was in fact all a matter of avoiding unnecessary (in theory) code. Like, imagine storing values of R, G and B in an array to create a color identical to Color.Black. Why do that when you can just use Color.Black? It's a needless process. So What I would do is try to avoid unnecessary process (always in theory). But if it can't be avoided, I'll proceed defining colors for all situations and that's it, whatever lol

If you have only 2 options and few colors @zohar-peled solution should be fine.
If you want something more scalable i think interface and classes is solution.
I don't know rest of your code so maybe there is reason why you can't use this (at least it can help someone else).
You didn't mention what default color is so i used light from zohar solution
interface ITheme
{
    Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin { get; }

    Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd { get; }
}

class DarkTheme : ITheme
{
    public Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(12, 46, 73); }
    }
    public Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(12, 46, 73); }
    }
}

class LightTheme : ITheme
{
    public Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(112, 146, 173); }
    }
    public Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(112, 146, 173); }
    }
}

enum ThemeEnum
{
    Dark,
    Light,
    SystemDefault
}

class MenuColorTable
{
    private ITheme _theme;

    public MenuColorTable(ThemeEnum theme)
    {
        switch (theme)
        {
            case ThemeEnum.Dark: _theme = new DarkTheme(); break;
            case ThemeEnum.Light: _theme = new LightTheme(); break;
            default: _theme = new LightTheme(); break;
        }
    }

    public Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin => _theme.MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin;

    public Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd => _theme.MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd;
}

each solution have it's pros and cons

Yes but as I stated the point is having a shorter code. In theory the UseSystemColorscan handle all the colors with the default system ones. It doesn't need to specify all the values, the environment has its own method to handle all the default colors and so you can just call that in one single instruction. But, since that instruction must be declared inside the colortable and I don't want to creare 2 different tables, my most straight take would be "this is the table: if condition, it uses default (i wouldn't need to specify all the values), else, i'm defining the new values".

this information would be usefull in original question :-D maybe add how you using this color (or getting default)
